# How to create and mount a loop-device with guestmount?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, loop-device, fuse

The goal is to test the out of disk space condition.

Creating an image:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1024 count=10000
```

Mountpoint:

```
mkdir mountpoint
```

Mounting fails:

```
guestmount -a test -m/dev/sda mountpoint
```

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda

Is there a need to create an fs? How to make the image usable?

(without the root user)

Comment: `/sbin/mkfs.ext4 test`